# No audio from DAC

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, manjaro

I'm no longer getting any sound out of my FiiO Q1 DAC.  The headphone port and monitor speakers still work and the DAC still works when in windows 10.  I've tried rebooting and fiddling with the settings in puleaudio.  The DAC appears in pulse audio and I can see that it's being sent audio - see the screenshot[image: Pulseaudio screenshot]

Output from `inxi -Fx`

```
will@will-manjaro ~> inxi -Fx 
    System:    Host: will-manjaro Kernel: 5.10.68-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.1.0 Desktop: i3 4.19.1 
               Distro: Manjaro Linux base: Arch Linux 
    Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX X370-F GAMING v: Rev X.0x serial: <superuser required> 
               UEFI: American Megatrends v: 4024 date: 09/07/2018 
    CPU:       Info: 8-Core model: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen+ rev: 2 cache: L2: 4 MiB 
               flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 118220 
               Speed: 3938 MHz min/max: 2200/3700 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3938 2: 2457 3: 3244 4: 3194 
               5: 2126 6: 2128 7: 2134 8: 2143 9: 2239 10: 2200 11: 2162 12: 2188 13: 4186 14: 4211 15: 3236 16: 3208 
    Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] driver: nvidia v: 470.63.01 bus-ID: 0a:00.0 
               Device-2: Logitech Webcam C270 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-14:4 
               Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: loaded: nvidia resolution: 1: 2560x1440~60Hz 2: 2560x1440 
               OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.63.01 direct render: Yes 
    Audio:     Device-1: NVIDIA GA102 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 0a:00.1 
               Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 17h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
               bus-ID: 0c:00.3 
               Device-3: SAVITECH FiiO USB DAC Q1 type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 1-11:2 
               Device-4: Logitech Webcam C270 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-14:4 
               Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.10.68-1-MANJARO running: yes 
               Sound Server-2: JACK v: 1.9.19 running: no 
               Sound Server-3: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes 
               Sound Server-4: PipeWire v: 0.3.37 running: yes 
    Network:   Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network vendor: ASUSTeK driver: igb v: kernel port: e000 bus-ID: 05:00.0 
               IF: enp5s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 18:31:bf:b8:c0:37 
    Bluetooth: Device-1: Cambridge Silicon Radio Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode) type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 5-2:3 
               Report: rfkill ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: see --recommends 
    Drives:    Local Storage: total: 2.5 TiB used: 310.57 GiB (12.1%) 
               ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Sabrent model: N/A size: 476.94 GiB temp: 28.9 C 
               ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Crucial model: CT256MX100SSD1 size: 238.47 GiB 
               ID-3: /dev/sdb vendor: TeamGroup model: L5Lite3D480G size: 447.13 GiB 
               ID-4: /dev/sdc vendor: Seagate model: ST3500418AS size: 465.76 GiB 
               ID-5: /dev/sdd vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EZEX-00RKKA0 size: 931.51 GiB 
    Partition: ID-1: / size: 66.79 GiB used: 36.68 GiB (54.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6 
               ID-2: /boot/efi size: 195.9 MiB used: 302 KiB (0.2%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sda3 
               ID-3: /home size: 468.45 GiB used: 273.89 GiB (58.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
    Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 66.41 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) dev: /dev/sda5 
    Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 44.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 34 C 
               Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 0% 
    Info:      Processes: 373 Uptime: 20m Memory: 47.06 GiB used: 3.62 GiB (7.7%) Init: systemd Compilers: gcc: 11.1.0 
               clang: 12.0.1 Packages: 1523 Shell: fish v: 3.3.1 inxi: 3.3.06
```

Output from `pacmd list-cards`

```
will@will-manjaro ~> pacmd list-cards                                                                                 (base) 
4 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.usb-262a_FiiO_USB_DAC_Q1-01>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "FiiO USB DAC Q1"
        alsa.long_card_name = "FiiO USB DAC Q1 at usb-0000:02:00.0-11, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:02:00.0-usb-0:11:1.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-11/1-11:1.1/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-262a_FiiO_USB_DAC_Q1-01"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "262a"
        device.vendor.name = "SAVITECH Corp."
        device.product.id = "100d"
        device.product.name = "FiiO USB DAC Q1"
        device.serial = "262a_FiiO_USB_DAC_Q1"
        device.string = "2"
        device.description = "FiiO USB DAC Q1"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    profiles:
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.usb-262a_FiiO_USB_DAC_Q1-01.analog-stereo/#4: FiiO USB DAC Q1 Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.usb-262a_FiiO_USB_DAC_Q1-01.analog-stereo.monitor/#6: Monitor of FiiO USB DAC Q1 Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.usb-046d_0825_9D2BA270-02>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "3"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x825"
        alsa.long_card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x825 at usb-0000:02:00.0-14, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:02:00.0-usb-0:14:1.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.2/sound/card3"
        udev.id = "usb-046d_0825_9D2BA270-02"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "046d"
        device.vendor.name = "Logitech, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0825"
        device.product.name = "Webcam C270"
        device.serial = "046d_0825_9D2BA270"
        device.form_factor = "webcam"
        device.string = "3"
        device.description = "Webcam C270"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
    profiles:
        input:mono-fallback: Mono Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <input:mono-fallback>
    sources:
        alsa_input.usb-046d_0825_9D2BA270-02.mono-fallback/#1: Webcam C270 Mono
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    index: 2
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_0a_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 89"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:0a:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0a:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1aef"
        device.product.name = "GA102 High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "GA102 High Definition Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 38468, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 38468, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra5: Digital Stereo (HDMI 6) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra5: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra5: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra6: Digital Stereo (HDMI 7) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra6: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 7) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra6: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 7) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo-extra1>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_0a_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1/#1: GA102 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_0a_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor/#2: Monitor of GA102 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "BenQ LCD
    "
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "AG241QG4
    "
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-5: HDMI / DisplayPort 6 (priority 5400, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-6: HDMI / DisplayPort 7 (priority 5300, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 3
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_0c_00.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 9
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xf7800000 irq 91"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:0c:00.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "1457"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 32833, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (priority 1300, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (priority 1200, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-41: Analog Surround 4.1 Output (priority 1300, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-50: Analog Surround 5.0 Output (priority 1200, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-51: Analog Surround 5.1 Output (priority 1300, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 38268, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 38333, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.3.iec958-stereo/#2: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller Digital Stereo (IEC958)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.3.iec958-stereo.monitor/#3: Monitor of Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller Digital Stereo (IEC958)
        alsa_input.pci-0000_0c_00.3.analog-stereo/#4: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
```